# JQuery dynamic dropdown menu on change populates other fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this dropdown (select) menu generated with JQuery, dynamically using JSON coming from PHP script.
Refer on the picture attached, under the Components label. The "select" menu holds Component name and Component ID (value). 
[image: example]

I want "on change" event, using JQuery, to populate the following fields Code, Category and UOM, with corresponding values.

My JSON object retrieves everything what is needed (I managed to achieve this with JQuery autocomplete).

eg.

```
[{"id":"4","component":"Component 1","code":"COMP1","uom":"kilo","category":"Flour"}...]
```

This is my code for generating the "select" menu with options inside coming from the above mentioned JSON.

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo site_url('products/dropdown/no'); ?>", function(result) {
            var optionsValues = '<select>';
            optionsValues += '<option value="">' + '--' + '</option>';
            $.each(result, function() {
            optionsValues += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.component + '</option>';
            });
            optionsValues += '</select>';
            var options = $("select[name=component]");
            options.replaceWith(optionsValues);  
        });
```

It is located in the $(document).ready.

So, I need function or something which whenever change in the "select" menu occurs, it will populate the mentioned fields around with corresponding values.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
   //Populate other fields
   //$.getJSON()
   //$('input.code').val(response.code)
   //etc...
});
```

Or if you generate the select element after the page has loaded, you can use:

```
$('select').live('change', function(){
   //Populate other fields
});
```

Comment: How do I refer to those specific values(code,category,uom) corresponding with the selected dropdown value?

Comment: In your getJSON function, you can grab the values from your php script using result.code, result.category etc. then you'll have to use $('input[name=code]').val(result.code) or whatever the field is called to add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select").change(function(){


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work:

Populating the select element, and storing the results in JSONObject variable:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/ci/index.php/products/dropdown/no", function(result) {
    var optionsValues = "<select id='component'>";
    JSONObject = result;
    optionsValues += '<option value="">' + '--' + '</option>';
    $.each(result, function() {
            optionsValues += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.prodname + '</option>';
    });
    optionsValues += '</select>';
    var options = $("select#component");
    options.replaceWith(optionsValues);  
});
```

When user change the values in the select menu:

```
$("select#component").live('change',function() {
            if(this.selectedIndex == '')
            {
                $("input#code").val('');  
                $("input#category").val('');  
                $("input#uom").val('');  
                return false;   
            }
          $("input#code").val(JSONObject[this.selectedIndex-1].code);  
          $("input#category").val(JSONObject[this.selectedIndex-1].pcname);  
          $("input#uom").val(JSONObject[this.selectedIndex-1].uname);
        });
```